# Parsing array of json object in ios swift 3.0

Tags: ios, json, swift3

Trying to parse a JSON array in iOS swift 3.0. But in XCode I always get to see this error:

> Type 'NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element' (aka 'Any') has no subscript members

The array I am trying to parse looks something like this:

```
[{"area_code":1,"area_name":"value"},{"area_code":2,"area_name":"value"},{"area_code":3,"area_name":"value"},{"area_code":4,"area_name":"value"}]
```

The code snippet of iOS looks something like this.

```
let json = try!JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableLeaves) as? NSArray

            // The JSONObjectWithData constructor didn't return an error. But, we should still
            // check and make sure that json has a value using optional binding.
            if let parseJSON = json {
                for dayData in parseJSON{

                    let areaObj = AreaCode()

                    if let areaCode = dayData["area_code"] as? Int{
                        areaObj.areaCode = areaCode
                    }
                    if let areaName = dayData["area_name"] as? String{
                        areaObj.areaName = areaName
                    }
                    areaCodeArray.append(areaObj)
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    // perform on main
                    self.onGetAreaList("Success");
                });
            }
```

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 you saved my day. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this way using `[[String:Any]]` instead `NSArray`

```
let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [[String:Any]]

     for dayData in json{
          let areaObj = AreaCode()

          if let areaCode = dayData["area_code"] as? Int{
              areaObj.areaCode = areaCode
          }

          if let areaName = dayData["area_name"] as? String{
               areaObj.areaName = areaName
          }

          areaCodeArray.append(areaObj)
```

Comment: why are you passing options as [] ?

Comment: If you don't want to use any options just use empty array @Zain as options need a type of an array to pass